# Automatically add menu item to WordPress Menu

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I found this sweet plugin that will automatically add a menu item to your custom menu for pages. All I need to do is tweak it to work for a hierarchal Custom Post Type. I'm thinking it will be easy for some of you... hopefully :) Thanks in advance.

Here it the code:

```
class AutoSubmenu {

/**
 * Constructor
 */
function __construct() {
    add_action( 'publish_page', array( &$this, 'on_publish_page' ) );
}

/**
 * When publishing a new child page, add it to the appropriate custom menu.
 */
function on_publish_page( $post_id ) {

    // Theme supports custom menus?
    if ( ! current_theme_supports( 'menus' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Published page has parent?
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( ! $post->post_parent ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get menus with auto_add enabled
    $auto_add = get_option( 'nav_menu_options' );
    if ( empty( $auto_add ) || ! is_array( $auto_add ) || ! isset( $auto_add['auto_add'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $auto_add = $auto_add['auto_add'];
    if ( empty( $auto_add ) || ! is_array( $auto_add ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Loop through the menus to find page parent
    foreach ( $auto_add as $menu_id ) {
        $menu_parent = NULL;
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_id, array( 'post_status' => 'publish,draft') );
        if ( ! is_array( $menu_items ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
            // Item already in menu?
            if ( $menu_item->object_id == $post->ID ) {
                continue 2;
            }
            if ( $menu_item->object_id == $post->post_parent ) {
                $menu_parent = $menu_item;
            }
        }
        // Add new item
        if ( $menu_parent ) {
            wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, 0, array(
                'menu-item-object-id' => $post->ID,
                'menu-item-object' => $post->post_type,
                'menu-item-parent-id' => $menu_parent->ID,
                'menu-item-type' => 'post_type', /*array( 'post_type' => 'bio_diversity')*/
                'menu-item-status' => 'publish'
            ) );
        }
    }
}

}

$auto_submenu = new AutoSubmenu();
```